# How the images storage works on Cryptokitties?

Tags: solidity, nft

As my research has shown there is this facts when it comes to Cryptokitties images:

- From the genome of each Kitty you can generate the image.
- Images are generated off chain by reading the this genome.
- The images are stored in google cloud.

What is still unclear for me:

- When and whose responsibility is it to upload the images onces a kitty is created?
- How does opensea know where to find the images?